# SQL Self Join + Another Join Not working

Tags: sql, self-join

I've got two tables, Job and User, and am trying to pull together some records. Job needs to be joined with User, and User to itself. The structure is:

```
 JobID | OwnerID | ClientName
   1   |    1    |   Corey
 -----------------------------
 UserID | ManagerID |    Name   | Email
    1   |     2     | Jon Smith | job@test.com
    2   |           | Jane Doe  | jane@test.com
```

I'm looking to obtain a table that contains the manager's email address, in addition to the user's name. My query is:

```
 SELECT 
      Job.ClientName as 'ClientName',
      U1.Name as 'SalesPersonName',
      U2.Email as 'ManagerEmail'
  FROM 
      Job
  INNER JOIN User U1 ON Job.OwnerID = U1.UserID
  INNER JOIN User U2 ON U1.UserID = U2.ManagerID
  WHERE 
      Job.ID = '1'
```

This pulls all Job data, and all data for U1...but is failing to populate U2 - the manager's information.

I imagine I've got something messed up with the self-join. The query validates, so I'm at a loss for what it is.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Note: the above table/column names have been simplified to protect the innocent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you juxtaposed the table aliases on the fields in your last `JOIN`:

This: `FULL JOIN User U2 ON U1.UserID = U2.ManagerID`

Should be this: `FULL JOIN User U2 ON U2.UserID = U1.ManagerID`

Full query:

```
SELECT 
    Job.ClientName as 'ClientName',
    U1.Name as 'SalesPersonName',
    U2.Email as 'ManagerEmail'
FROM 
    Job
FULL JOIN User U1 ON Job.OwnerID = U1.UserID
FULL JOIN User U2 ON U2.UserID = U1.ManagerID
WHERE 
    Job.ID = 1 --removed ticks here, assuming int column
```

Note: You don't need a `FULL JOIN` unless there are records that won't join together, and you want to preserve those records with `NULL` values in your result set.  For the example provided, a basic `INNER JOIN` would work, but maybe you need the `FULL JOIN` for your true data set so I left it in.

Note 2: `user` is a reserved word in many DBMS and could cause you headaches if used as a tablename

Comment: Yep - silly mistake on my part. It's amazing the little things that'll drive you nuts. Thanks for spotting this for me!

Comment: @Corey Any good coding effort requires someone looking over your shoulder to catch the silly stuff. :)